# BaseUrl changes occasionally when using the Webclient in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, webclient

Depending on the situation, there is a WebClient logic that sends requests to each MSA server.

For example,

```
http://msa-a/~, http://msa-b/~
```

It works well, but when there are many requests for the logic, in the case of A, A msa should be called, but other Msa is called intermittently.

There is a webclient config as shown below.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebClient.Builder webClient(){

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
            .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000)));

    return WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeaders(headers -> headers.addAll(httpHeaders))
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(10 * 1024 * 1024));
  }
```

BaseUrl and path are dynamically allocated as follows.

At this time, if there are many requests, for example, you have to send a request to A, but baseUrl is sometimes designated as a different server, and if you send a request, 404 errors occur.

```
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder builder;

public Mono<JSONObject> callApi(MyApi api, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, Object body) {

    WebClient client = builder
        .baseUrl(api.getBaseUrl())
        .build();

    RequestBodySpec spec = null;

    if (api.getHttpMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET)){
      MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
      if (body != null) {
        map.setAll((HashMap) body);
      }

      spec = client.method(api.getHttpMethod())
          .uri(builder -> builder
              .path(api.getPath())
              .queryParams(map)
              .build())
          .headers(headers -> {
            if (webClientHeader != null) {
              headers.addAll(webClientHeader);
            }
          })
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
    else {
      spec = (RequestBodySpec) client.method(api.getHttpMethod())
          .uri(builder -> builder
              .path(api.getPath())
              .build())
          .headers(headers -> {
            if (webClientHeader != null) {
              headers.addAll(webClientHeader);
            }
          })
          .bodyValue(body)
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    Mono<JSONObject> result = spec
        // exchangeToMono
        .exchangeToMono(res -> {
          if (res.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            return res.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class);
          }
          if (res.statusCode().is4xxClientError() || res.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
            return res.createException()
                .flatMap(it -> Mono.error(it));
          }
          else {
            return res.createException()
                .flatMap(it -> Mono.error(it));
          }
        })
        .doOnError(error -> log.error(error.getMessage()))
        .onErrorResume(err -> {
          throw new WebClientRetryException();
        });

    return result.flatMap(res -> {
      log.info("Call Url => " + (api.getDomain() + api.getEndPoint()));
      log.info("Call Header => " + webClientHeader);
      log.info("Call QueryParam & Body => " + body);

      JSONObject conversion = new JSONObject(res);
      return Mono.just(conversion);
    });
  }
```

What's the reason? How can I solve it?